# Invoking different methods on threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main process `main`. It creates 10 threads (say) and then what i want to do is the following:

```
while(required){
Thread t= new Thread(new ClassImplementingRunnable());
t.start();
counter++;
}
```

Now i have the list of these threads, and for each thread i want to do a set of process, same for all, hence i put that implementation in the run method of `ClassImplementingRunnable`.

Now after the threads have done their execution, i wan to wait for all of them to stop, and then evoke them again, but this time i want to do them serially not in parallel.

for this I join each thread, to wait for them to finish execution but after that i am not sure how to evoke them again and run that piece of code serially.
Can i do something like

```
for(each thread){
t.reevoke(); //how can i do that.
t.doThis();  // Also where does `dothis()` go, given that my ClassImplementingRunnable is an inner class.
}
```

Also, i want to use the same thread, i.e. i want the  to continue from where they left off, but in a serial manner.
I am not sure how to go about the last piece of pseudo code. 
Kindly help.
Working with with java.

Comment: So you want to test if it is faster to start all threads at the same time (in parallel) vs. to start them serially?

Comment: What is `doThis`? Does it refer to the `run` method of the `Runnables`?

Comment: `this time i want to do them serially not in parallel.` In this case you don't want multiple thread, you want just one i.e. the one which called the threads.  You can't restart a thread once it has finished.

Comment: A thread cannot be restarted. Once it finishing you will have to create a new thread with your runnable.

Comment: but if i create new threads they wont know what the previous threads have done, sicne all the objects created by them will be lost, or not? How can i access the changes made by the previous threads?

Comment: Few classes you might find interesting and useful compared to manual creating of threads and waiting for them: [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: Try the Future object on some of the java 5 executor services. This is returned after the thread has finished. You could use that to store state

Comment: @Kraken: Threads share all of memory. All changes made by the previous threads will be visible to any other thread that accesses the changed objects. Also, the basic answer to your question is this -- you tell the threads what to do, so write code that does exactly what you want the threads to do and then tell the threads to run that code. You are making this much more difficult than it needs to do by trying to push the threads around from the outside. There is no need, code them from the inside to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't restart a thread.

What you could do is use the java.util.concurrent package to wait for the threads to finish and rerun you runnables in the main thread to run them sequentially - by putting your runnables in a list, you can access them during the sequential run.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<Runnable> ();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Runnable r = new ClassImplementingRunnable();
    runnables.add(r);
    executor.submit(r);
}

executor.shutdown();
//wait until all tasks are finished
executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//re run the tasks sequentially
for (ClassImplementingRunnable r : runnables) {
    //the method below can access some variable in 
    //your ClassImplementingRunnable object, that was 
    //set during the first parallel run
    r.doSomethingElse(); 
}
```

Comment: This answer beats mine because it urges to switch to Executors and shows the actual code needed to do it. With this approach the solution could be improved by using `Callable` and starting to print the result of `Future.get()` right away, blocking as necessary while waiting for a task to finish.

Answer (score 3):

If you want serial execution, just use

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  new ClassImplementingRunnable().run();
```

all the tasks will run in the same thread, one after the other. This is the cleanest way to achieve what you want.

## Update

After your comment it is clear that you in fact don't want to run the same tasks again, but to print the results that were calculated by them. This would be even simpler:

1. add the `ClassImplementingRunnable` instances into a list of tasks;
2. run each task in its own thread;
3. join all the threads;
4. write a `for` loop that prints the results from each `ClassImplementingRunnable` instance.

You already have 2 and 3.

Comment: say, my first thread created some list and so did the second one and so on, but all with different data. now what if i want to print that data, if i put this printing thing in the run method only, it will give me bizarre results since they all will interfere with each other.

Comment: and the way you suggested , i dont think i will be able to remember the states where each thread left off. or will I?

Comment: You haven't made your requirements clear, then. Once you have run a task, there's little sense in running the exact same task again. If you want to print the results, that's not the same task as calculating the results. What you then need is just a simple `for` loop that reads the lists calculated by those tasks and prints them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like 
**ExecutorCompletionService**

Example copied from Java doc.

> **Usage Examples.** Suppose you have a set of solvers for a certain problem, each returning a value of some type Result, and would like to run them concurrently, processing the results of each of them that return a non-null value, in some method use(Result r). You could write this as:

```
void solve(Executor e,
          Collection<Callable<Result>> solvers)
 throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
   CompletionService<Result> ecs
       = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(e);
   for (Callable<Result> s : solvers)
       ecs.submit(s);
   int n = solvers.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       Result r = ecs.take().get();
       if (r != null)
           use(r);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some great answers here, I'm not sure your initial questions have been answered.

> Now after the threads have done their execution, i wan to wait for all of them to stop, and then evoke them again, but this time i want to do them serially not in parallel.

You are confusing the running thread from it's object.  It is a very common pattern (although usually made better with the `ExecutiveService` classes) to do something like the following:

```
List<ClassExtendingThread> threads = new ArrayList<ClassExtendingThread>();
// create your list of objects
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ClassExtendingThread thread = new ClassExtendingThread(...);
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
}

for (ClassExtendingThread thread : threads) {
    // now wait for each of them to finish in turn
    thread.join();
    // call some method on them to get their results
    thread.doThis();
}
```

Notice that I changed your class to extending `Thread`.  It is usually better to implement `Runnable` like you did but if you are going to be joining and calling back to the objects, extending `Thread` makes the code easier.

So you create your object instances, start them as threads, and then `join()` with them which both waits for them to finish and synchronizes their memory.  Once you `join()` with the thread, you can call any of the methods on your objects that you'd like.  That doesn't "re-evoke" the thread at all.  It is just accessing the fields inside of your objects.  If you try to do this while the thread is running then you need to worry about `synchronization`.